# AMP Email always shows "Discard email draft" dialog box in Gmail web app

Tags: amp-email

AMP Email works well on Gmail mobile app. However on the web version, it shows this popup message when I try to navigate out the AMP Email without making any changes to the form elements:

> ### Discard email draft
>
> **Changes made within this email will be lost**

I have my form inside the amp-list:

```
  <amp-list items="logs" width="100" height="100" layout="responsive" id="comments"
    src="...">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
      <div class="entry">
        ...
      </div>
      {{#last}}
        <form id="commentbox" method="post" on="submit-success:comments.refresh,commentbox.clear"
          action-xhr="...">
          ...
        </form>
      {{/last}}
    </template>
  </amp-list>
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Copy this HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email data-css-strict>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script custom-element="amp-timeago" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-timeago-0.1.js" async></script>
  <script custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js" async></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
  <style amp-custom>
    body{ font:small/1.5 Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
    .response{ padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:15px; }
    .task{ 
      width:100%; margin:auto; padding-top:20px;
      border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    }

    .entry{
      display:grid; width:98%; 
      grid-template-columns:80px auto max(110px); column-gap:10px;
      grid-template-rows:30px auto; padding-bottom:30px;
      grid-template-areas:'status by ago' 'empty message message';
    }
    .status{ grid-area:status; overflow:hidden; }
    .status span{ vertical-align:top; padding:5px 10px;
      width:58px; text-align:center; font-size:12px; font-weight:500; line-height:22px;
      border-radius: 100px; color: #522AE9; background-color: #dad1fd; }
    .by{ grid-area:by; overflow:hidden; font-size:12px; color:#666; padding:5px 5px 5px 0px; }
    .message{ grid-area:message; font-size:14px; color:#000; }
    .ago{ grid-area:ago; font-size:12px; color:#666; padding:5px 5px 5px 0px; text-align:right; }

    #commentbox fieldset{ padding:0px; border:none; }
    #commentbox .comment-status{ padding-bottom:10px; font-weight:500; color:#522ae9; }
    #commentbox .comment-status[submit-error]{ color:#dc3545; }
    #commentbox .comment-status[submit-success]{ color:#1c7e26; }
    .comment-box{ 
      background:#F6F6F6; padding:15px; border-radius:5px; 
      margin-bottom:20px; text-align:right; 
      display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
    }
    .comment-box textarea{ 
      display:block; width:100%; grid-column-start:1; grid-column-end:8; padding:4px; 
      font-family:arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px;
      color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .comment-box select{ 
      padding:2px; height:28px; margin-top:18px; 
      font-family:arial;  font-size:14px; line-height:16px;
      color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); background-color: #fff; background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .comment-box .submit{
      display: inline-block; padding: 5px 10px; margin-top:10px; cursor:pointer;
      font-size: 14px; line-height:22px; letter-spacing: 0; border-radius: 5px;
      color: #fff; background-color: #3f1bca; border: 1px solid #522AE9;
    }

    @media (max-width:800px){
      .status span{ padding:2px 5px; font-size:9px; font-weight:400; }
      .by{ font-size:9px; }
      .message{ font-size:12px; }
      .ago{ font-size:9px; }
      .comment-box textarea{ font-size:12px; }
      .comment-box select{ font-size:12px; }
      .comment-box .submit{ font-size:12px; }
    }
    @media (min-width:801px){
      .status{ padding-top:3px; }
      .entry{ column-gap:30px; width:100%; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="task">
    <amp-list items="logs" width="100" height="100" layout="responsive" id="comments" src="https://mailrecipe.com/pers/amp/1FAIpQLSfnGpEj7duU4VlD46-5mVgAMvrnNpZesL-WGJQsN3QkMjVCJw/response/2_ABaOnuemdRDB6PSNQviuv-wC0RnvILP7RlGVuL9RiX8VhWjEWGYgaXYKTeY-aMb_JXBtuXo">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div class="entry">
          <div class="status">
            <span style="color:{{color}}; background-color:{{bg}};">{{tab}}</span>
          </div>
          <span class="by">
            {{by}}
          </span>
          <span class="ago">
            <amp-timeago height="30" datetime="{{date}}" locale="en">
              {{date}}
            </amp-timeago>
          </span>
          <div class="message">{{comment}}</div>
        </div>
        {{#last}}
          <form id="commentbox" method="post" on="submit-success:comments.refresh,commentbox.clear" action-xhr="https://mailrecipe.com/pers/amp/1FAIpQLSfnGpEj7duU4VlD46-5mVgAMvrnNpZesL-WGJQsN3QkMjVCJw/response/2_ABaOnuemdRDB6PSNQviuv-wC0RnvILP7RlGVuL9RiX8VhWjEWGYgaXYKTeY-aMb_JXBtuXo">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="comment-status" submitting>
                Updating your comment ...
              </div>
              <div class="comment-status" submit-success>
                Your comment has been updated!
              </div>
              <div class="comment-status" submit-error>
                Update failed!
              </div>
              <div class="comment-box text-right">
                <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment"></textarea>
                <select name="moveto">
                  <option value="">- Move to -</option>
                  <option value="submitted">Submitted</option>
                  <option value="approved">Completed</option>
                  <option value="archive">Trash</option>
                </select>
                <div></div>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send">
                <input type="hidden" name="by" value="mani.doraisamy@gmail.com">
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
          <br />
        {{/last}}
      </template>
    </amp-list>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Go to [Gmail playground](https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/) to send AMP email to yourself.
3. Open your Gmail web version and view this email
4. Navigate out of the email without making any changes to the form field to see the Discard dialogbox.

How do I avoid this dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in AMP. The code that determines whether the form is in its initial "default" state (and thus whether the form is initially dirty) is checking the `defaultSelected` attribute of the `<option>` element, which will always be `false` if you don't have the selected HTML attributes added to the `<option>` element, even though the user agent will make the first option selected in absence of the selected attribute:

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/6ed742c2d07f4cc4640b5c622d77d53244826dd9/src/form.js#L179

As a workaround, add the `selected` attribute to your first option under your `<select>` and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation about this behavior in the Gmail developer documentation:

> When the email contains a form with input elements, if the inputs are changed the user may see a confirmation before navigating away from the email without submitting the form. This confirmation isn't shown in some cases, such as if the user clears the form or upon message deletion.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/tips

You can't disable this dialog box. It's a feature for the Gmail users to prevent them from losing data. The user needs to do one of the following upon seeing the dialog:

- Click "Cancel" and submit the form so that any pending data they have entered is not lost
- Click "Cancel" and clear the input fields to intentionally discard pending form data
- Click "Discard" to intentionally discard pending form data

Once the user successfully submits the form, then the dialog will not be shown.

Comment: This does not happen when the user has made any change to the input elements. It always shows this dialog box in the web app (not in mobile app) even if I just view the email and navigate outside. This happens only when the form is inside the amp-list.

Comment: You will need to provide a minimal sample email that reproduces the issue for others to help you diagnose what's going on.

Comment: I have added the sample email in my question above and the steps to replicate the issue. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a bug in AMP. The code that determines whether the form is in its initial "default" state (and thus whether the form is initially dirty) is checking the `defaultSelected` attributed of the `<option>` element, which will always be `false` if you don't have the `selected` HTML attributes added to the `<option>` element, even though the user agent will make the first option selected in absence of the `selected` attribute.

As a workaround, add the `selected` attribute to your first option under your `<select>` and then it should work.

Comment: The bug is here btw: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/6ed742c2d07f4cc4640b5c622d77d53244826dd9/src/form.js#L179

Comment: Awesome! That's a perfectly valid workaround. If you can post it as a separate answer, I can mark it as the correct answer.